# error occurred with error type -parseerror and status code - 200

Tags: javascript, json, file-upload

I have a function of upload file using json. I have the necessary error messages for invalid file, wrong file format, empty file and etc..

But recently when upload file have this new error which i didnt declare the error message

Error message: "error occurred with error type -parseerror and status code - 200"

Tried googling but found code 200 mean ok? what does this error mean?

Comment: Can you share the entire error message here? It would be helpful to understand what has happened then.

Comment: The error message "error occurred with error type -parseerror and status code - 200". this is the only error message.

Comment: Please consider adding your code samples.